# Rendering code in Firepad using CodeMirror

Tags: firebase, firepad

I'm using [FirePad](https://github.com/firebase/firepad/) to create an IDE of sorts for myself. What I'm trying to do is use the userlist.html in examples/ to render JS code. This is done in examples/code.html, and I've changed:

```
var codeMirror = CodeMirror(document.getElementById('firepad'), { lineWrapping: true });
```

to

```
var codeMirror = CodeMirror(document.getElementById('firepad'), {
  lineNumbers: true,
  mode: 'javascript'
});
```

It does display the line numbers, but it does not highlight the JS.

To clarify, I'm making these changes in examples/userlist.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to include the javascript mode file as well:

```
<script src="codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
```

Comment: One more thing. When I have `mode: 'html/text'`, and reference `codemirror/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js`, it doesn't highlight HTML :(

Comment: Take a look at all the mode examples on http://codemirror.net/ in particular the HTML mixed-mode one: http://codemirror.net/mode/htmlmixed/index.html  You should be able to use it as a starting point.

Comment: I have. Why wouldn't the above code work? It's what they have in the examples

Comment: Did you include the XML, JavaScript, and CSS mode files as the page describes? :-)

Comment: One thing that may not be obvious is that CodeMirror modes have dependencies you have to take care of. For instance, PHP mode is based on C-like, and depends on XML, JavaScript, CSS, HTMLMixed as well.